# RDF vocabulary for units

Tags: rdf, vocabulary

I am looking for a RDF vocabulary that describes the unit [**gross tonnage**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_tonnage). I have browsed the [qudt](http://qudt.org/vocab/unit/#) unit vocabulary without finding the unit I am looking for. Can't seem to find a vocabulary describing gross tonnage when searching around either. Does anyone know a vocabulary I can dive into to find this unit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not done so, I advise you to search for this term on platforms such as [LOV (Linked Open Vocabularies)](https://lov.linkeddata.es/dataset/lov/), which allow you to search for vocabularies and terms within vocabularies that are referenced by the platform.

By searching [gross tonnage](https://lov.linkeddata.es/dataset/lov/terms?q=Gross+tonnage) you will have a few hits such as [GrossWeightCharacteristic](http://vocab.datex.org/terms/#GrossWeightCharacteristic), the *"Gross weight characteristic of a vehicle"* (but I couldn't tell if it's really what you need).

There is other plateforms allowing to search for terms in vocabularies, such as [OntoBee](http://www.ontobee.org/), the [EMBL-EBI Ontology Lookup Service](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/index) (for biomedical ontologies) or the [MMI Ontology Registry and Repository (ORR)](https://mmisw.org/) (for marine science).

Comment: Thank you so much! ORR seems to be the perfect fit for me, as I am describing ships.